# How do I smoothe Vertices of a mesh

Tags: mesh, vertices

is there a way to edit vertices in a Mesh like I can edit them in a Curve. In this case I need to smoothe the folds or creases as if the Vertices had bezier handles.In the End the folds should be rounded.

I created this from a plane -> cut the plane evenly in x -> checker selected the Edges and pulled every 2nd edge up.

any better Idea on how to build this maybe using a spline?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you want, do you want this to be built by curve so that you can animate it later? Because if you don't need to animate it, you should just bevel this object that you already have

Comment: I think if you need to add geometry in order to smooth, then that's what subdivision surface does? Otherwise LoopTools addon, *Relax* for example.

Comment: if you want to smooth these folds, you can bevel these edges

Comment: @MikoCG : I haven´t thought about it, but indeed I need to animate the object later. In this case, how would you build it using a spline?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady :Thank you Markus, that is how it is supposed to look like. I havent worked with the looptools but will try.

Comment: @elBrandzo you want to animate how this objects goes from straight to this? Or somehing different? Because if you want to animate how plane changes to this zig zag, then you should use curve with plane as array on it and animate that curve that will control your object

Comment: No, actually I need to bend the whole object as you see it now, including the zigzag pattern...